# Android autocompletetextview suggestions drop down appear below soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a AutoCompleteTextView set up at the bottom of the screen, below a map fragment. The soft keyboard push both of them up when it appears. The suggestions layout doesn't seem to detect the keyboard however, and expands downwards, hiding all the suggestions.

I know this question has been asked here some times, but all of the solutions seems out of date, as none of them remedy the problem. I've also tried various R.layout.x, but none of them seem to detect the keyboard.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auto_complete_search_map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_search"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_in_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

        search = findViewById(R.id.search_in_map);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, PLACE_TYPES);
        user_input = findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_search_map);
        user_input.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Is there anyway to simply force the list to expand up instead of down? If not, what are some other viable means to fix this? Placing the AutoCompleteTextView at the top would fix this, but that wouldn't be optimal considering this is the main feature of this activity and should be easily reachable on the screen.

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 0):

AutoCompleteTextView decides to open down or up based on available space: if it has more space up it will expand up and if it has more space down it will expand down.
All you have to do is to adjust your layout in sort that the AutoCompleteTextView expands on the desired direction.

Comment: There is no space below though. The AutoCompleteTextView is placed at the bottom of a vertical linear layout that spans the entire view. It seems that it is not aware that the soft keyboard is occupying the space below when it pushes the linear layout up to make space for the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping all the layout inside a `ScrollView` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout  
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             ...
```

If I'm not wrong I did it time ago in a log in screen and the keyboard uses the `ScrollView` so that the content should not be hidden.